# How to debug: Unexpected token '<' : <html lang="en">

Tags: jquery, html, reactjs

Deploying our react-app to firebase these past few days have shown us some unexpected errors. We have a script in the index.html file that is throwing this error.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>THE RISE COLLECTION | Software Development</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="jiosh_">
    <meta name="description" content="THE RISE COLLECTION | Innovating Without Forgetting To Be Creative">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/css/main.05c6e305.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="landing-page" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="75">
    <div class="loader-wrapper"><div class="loader">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="root">
  </div>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="assets/js/land-scripts.js">
  </script>
  <div id="color">
  </div>
  <script src="assets/js/script.js">
  </script>
  <script src="assets/js/scroll.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.5533582a.js">
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

what the script shows in the google chrome console :

```
<html lang="en"> <- error coming from this line
  <head>
    <title>THE RISE COLLECTION | Software Development</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="jiosh_">
    <meta name="description" content="THE RISE COLLECTION | Innovating Without Forgetting To Be Creative">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/css/main.05c6e305.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="landing-page" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="75">
    <div class="loader-wrapper"><div class="loader">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="root">
  </div>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="assets/js/land-scripts.js">
  </script>
  <div id="color">
  </div>
  <script src="assets/js/script.js">
  </script>
  <script src="assets/js/scroll.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.5533582a.js">
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I have gone through quite a few questions and have yet to find a solution that works. This project is a react-app.

*Note*
I have tried removing/readding "text/javascript" along with changing the src tag to just the file name.

Comment: That sounds like an HTML page (probably a custom error page) being returned to something that was probably expecting JSON. Have you inspected the network tab in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: @TiesonT. https://gyazo.com/fd37e6564d53cc103de4915938f70ad3 Here is a screenshot of the network tab with that file selected specifically.  The content type for the file even though its set to "text/javascript" project side.. on the production build content type is text/hmtl

Answer (score 1):

Your file type is js, and ends in `.js` 
Somewhere you need to output a .html file, even if all it does is load the .js file.

In firebase i thin you can add a config file to declare redirects, ie i'm a single page app, always serve index.html

-_- g'luck

Comment: just figured it out seconds ago... type was changed to "text/html" and the public param in the firebase config wase changed to build and the project is now live.

Answer (score 0):

the type was changed to "text/html"

firebase config setting "public" was changed to build serving the react-app project correctly